# Are perfect sets compact in R?

Tags: real-analysis

By the definitions of perfect and compact sets, are perfect sets, compact in $\mathbb{R}^n?$
What about in topological space?

Comment: What about the  perfect set $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: $\mathbb R^{n}$ is perfect but not compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, a set $A$ is perfect if $\text{der}(A)=A$ where $\text{der}$ denotes the set of accumulation points. $\mathbb{R}^n$ is perfect and non-compact. And clearly, if you take a non-compact topological space $X$ then it's perfect but non-compact.

Comment: very well, but can you give me an example with a subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Take $(-\infty,0]$. It's perfect but not compact.